# Is uploading and downloading an image in same ajax call worth it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, server

I have a web app that involves uploading an image and then downloading an image right after. Before I used to upload an image, then get back the url to the image, then make a second request to download the image from the url. I changed it now so that I upload the image, and the response is the raw binary of the return image, which then I convert into base64 (on client side) and then insert that as image in the DOM, all this in 1 ajax call. It takes the same time or longer for the new image to show on the page because of the extra conversions. I just want to know is it worth doing it in this new way or not in order to keep the server using less cpu?

Comment: It seems doing the extra conversions to base64 and all that uses more CPU.. if you not micro managing it doesn't matter. Only thing I can think of the base64 wont get cached on next load, so the benefit of loading from URL is caching.

Comment: You are hosting the image files in both cases, or where the files being hosted and served from an **external** provider?

Comment: @ppumkin The conversion to base64 happens on the client side, and i'm concerned about the cpu on the server side.

Comment: Caching doesn't matter because the image being returned is being dynamically generated/created on server side and returned.

Comment: OK, well that good to offload the processing to the client.. but as I mentioned, without caching you will actually have to send that image twice to the client.. because the base64 wont be cached. Also, in general its better for AJAX to do one thing at a time.. not essential obviosly but sending binary from AJAX is on the extreme side for serving images.

Comment: If caching doenst matter... then no. your solution is actually pretty much saving you resources then in the `n^10` request range.

Answer (score 0):

CPU, no. The only win here is in reduction of HTTP header traffic (and hence, client latency), which only becomes significant when the amount of calls multiplied by the cost of that traffic relative to the size of the download exceeds around 1/2 of the download, ie:
    isWorthIt = (Number of Reload Calls) * (size of HTTP headers for calls) > (size of Image) / 2

(roughly speaking). So if you're not doing lots of these calls from the same page, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: So this technique is only useful when there are tons of clients connecting?

Comment: Well, more like when one client is doing tons of image requests, unless the different clients are all doing the same requests.